# phpmyadmin database export is in binary

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, export

I am using phpmyadmin (ver. 3.3.8) to export a database of a website that I have with a hosting provider (hence my only method of doing a backup). When I do the export, I have the following options set:

```
Export: SQL

Within the OPTIONS group; under the STRUCTURE sub group,
Selected the check box next to "Structure"
Selected the check box labeled "Add AUTO_INCREMENT value"
Selected the check box labeled "Enclose table and field names with backquotes"

Within the OPTIONS group, under the DATA sub group:
Selected the check box marked "Complete inserts".
Selected the check box marked "Extended inserts".
Selected the check box labeled "Use hexadecimal for binary fields" may be selected
Selected "INSERT" in the combo box labeled "Export type:"

Selected to gzip the exported file.
```

The resulting file looks like it is in binary (and not SQL as I expected). I tried importing the binary file but of course that fails. How do I fix this so that the exported file works on import? I never had this problem with any other site.

Thanks.

Comment: Is it gzipping or bzipping the file before sending it, perhaps?

Comment: I have it set up to gzip the file. I just tried backing it up with no compression and it looks as it should. Why would gzipping it cause this to happen? I have never had that problem before gzipping the the file.

Comment: because gzipped data is compressed data. it's **NOT** human readable until you decompress it. You're basically complaining about your car being blue after you painted it blue.

Comment: Thanks for the condescending and snarky comment but I uncompressed the file first to check its contents before posting about my problem here. And yes the uncompressed file is still in binary format. If you don't have anything useful to add, perhaps you should refrain from commenting.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to my problem by not selecting to to compress the exported file. For some reason in this particular situation, selecting to compress the output causes the export to become corrupt. Why this is, I have no idea, as I have used this option successfully before until now (perhaps the hosting provider has some sort of weird set up). If you are experiencing the same issue then try using no compression, and see if it solves it for you.